# ¿Cómo optimizarías este código en python?

Tags: python, optimizar

Es un funcion que ve si un caracter es una vocal o no. Se que es muy simple pero quisiera saber como se podria mejorar el codigo sin escribir muchos condicionales.

```
def devuelve_vocal(caracter):
    if caracter == 'a' or caracter == 'e' or caracter == 'i' or caracter == 'o' or caracter == 'u':
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(devuelve_vocal('v'))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def devuelve_vocal(caracter):
    return caracter.lower() in "aeiou"
```

La expresión `caracter.lower() in "aeiou"` se evalua como `True` o `False`, según sea vocal o no.

Basta con retornar directamente el resultado de la evaluación.

Answer (score 3):

Lo único que se me ocurre es ver si está en un string de vocales.

```
def  devuelve_vocal(caracter):
  if caracter.lower() in 'aeiou':   
    return True
  else:  return False

print(devuelve_vocal('v'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que así quedaría más optimizado, no tienes que ir poniendo letra por letra, creas una lista y aplicas in para consultar si el carácter está dentro de las vocales

```
    def devuelve_vocal(caracter):
    vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    if caracter in vocales:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(devuelve_vocal('u'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Crea un arreglo con las letras que quieres filtrar, en este caso las vocales, y luego en una condicional compruebas si el arreglo contiene esa letra

```
vocales = [
    'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'
]

def comprobarVocales(vocal):
    if vocal.lower() not in vocales:
        print(False)
    else:
        print(True)

comprobarVocales('S')
```

Le agregué `.lower()` para que no tengas que agregar las mayusculas también, si no que directamente puedes comprobar si las letras *A, a, E, e, I, i, O, o, U, u* sin necesidad de cargar mas memoria a tu programa

Comment: Cuantos puntos de mi curso de inteligencia artificial voy a ganar sii resuelvo el problema?? Aqui ayudamos a resolver problemas de codigo, no a hacerte la tarea... Reformula tu pregunta con muestras de codigo que has tratado y donde te has quedado atascado